# Sinch IM: Page reloads after message is sent

Tags: javascript, sinch

**I have a simple** form that contains two inputs, asking for the recepient(s) and the message content.

**Upon submission of the** form, the message is sent to the appropriate recepient(s). The first time the form is submitted, all goes well. But then the second time the form is submitted, the page reloads and the message is not sent.

```
document.getElementById("imForm__sendMessage").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var message = messageClient.newMessage(document.getElementById("imForm__recepientField").value.trim(), document.getElementById("imForm__messageField").value.trim())
    messageClient.send(message).fail(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    return false;
});
```

**The above is** the "relevant" code, you can find the full JS file [here](https://pastebin.com/FQHyAdYF) and you can also find the HTML file [here](https://pastebin.com/2gGiMAi3).

**Where are the errors** you may ask. On the first sending, no errors are flagged. On the second sending, the page refreshes too quickly to catch an error (if there even is one)

**I have looked at the IM Sample** quite a lot of times. And there are no distinct differences in between our codes except the fact that, in the sample, they use JQuery...which I do not.

Comment: `The above is the "relevant" code, you can find the full JS file here` - the issue I have with this statement is that the `relevant code` does not appear in the `full JS`

Comment: `the page refreshes too quickly to catch an error` turn on persistent console logging in your browser developer tools - how? depends on the browser you are using

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for telling me that :D it should include it now

Comment: Assuming that for Chrome "preserving logs" allows for persistent logging, Chrome isn't showing an error :|

Comment: well, at least `(if there even is one)` is answered :p

Comment: Since you are doing preventDefault and the page refreshes it seems that you are doing something wrong there, it should not refresh if you are preventDefault();

Comment: Since you are doing preventDefault and the page refreshes it seems that you are doing something wrong there, it should not refresh if you are preventDefault();

Comment: @cjensen Good observation :D